# How to use a Woocommerce Rest API to list all orders from a payment_method

Tags: api, woocommerce

i follow the Woocommerce Rest api documentation to list all orders from specific payment_method but not working for me. I try to use two ways:

1)
wp-json/wc/v3/orders?search=banking-ticket

2)
wp-json/wc/v3/orders?payment_method=banking-ticket

Answer (score -2):

I consult the Woocommerce API and fix my problem

Comment: Whats the solution you came up with?